# Data point missing when conducing phylogenetic independent contrasts on R

Tags: r

I am conducting a phylogenetic independent contrast on sex ratios in 200 bird species using RStudio. I need to be able to identify which post-contrast value is from which species so I can find an outlier. However, the row names disappear when I conduct the pic and when I try to add them, I get the error message
`Error in names(csr) <- row.names(data) :  'names' attribute [200] must be the same length as the vector [199]`
I downloaded my pic values for 'csr' to a .csv and found that the length is indeed now 199. Why is a species missing and how can I attach the species name to my pic values?
Quick note: I thought maybe this was an issue of duplicate data in my original data frame but I checked and none of my species are duplicated.
New R user, thanks in advance!

```
Library(ape)
Library(maps)
Library(phytools)
Library(geiger)
#upload data
>data<-read.csv(file.choose(),row.names=1)
#upload set of trees
> et<-read.nexus(file.choose())
#form consensus tree
> cet<-consensus.edges(et,"least.squares")
[1] "RSS: 74.744666106374"
#make tree dichotomous
> rcet<-multi2di(cet)
#check tree and data match up
> name.check(rcet,data)
[1] "OK"
> sr<-data$SR
> names(sr)<-row.names(data)
> csr<-pic(sr,rcet)
#check to see if row names are attached
>head.matrix(csr)
          201           202           203           204 
 5.090712e-04 -9.531727e-04  1.648872e-03 -4.288288e-03 
          205           206           207           208 
 1.460023e-03  1.940847e-03  1.430754e-03  8.495663e-04 
          209           210           211           212 
-1.590387e-03 -4.440047e-03  5.930776e-03  3.885212e-03 
          213           214           215           216 
-8.180639e-03  4.020204e-03  9.256576e-03  2.211563e-02 
          217           218           219           220 
-1.236238e-02  2.187909e-02  8.064300e-03  2.221089e-02 
          221           222           223           224 
-2.730282e-02  5.591690e-03 -1.043775e-02 -5.360213e-03 
          225           226           227           228 
 1.414753e-02  1.078473e-02 -2.452003e-03  2.211674e-03 
          229           230           231           232 
 3.004410e-03 -5.365461e-03 -5.391057e-03  5.968397e-03 
          233           234           235           236 
 8.282451e-03 -7.260091e-03  4.575852e-03  2.860073e-03 
          237           238           239           240 
 1.052456e-02 -1.903541e-03  1.125396e-02  6.927645e-03 
          241           242           243           244 
-3.089605e-02 -1.153509e-02  3.953120e-02  5.213560e-02 
          245           246           247           248 
 5.349170e-03  1.309613e-03  8.532669e-03  3.641861e-02 
          249           250           251           252 
-2.571262e-02  2.900506e-03 -3.481454e-02 -6.424101e-03 
          253           254           255           256 
 9.802964e-03 -3.150135e-03 -1.101131e-02 -2.131249e-02 
          257           258           259           260 
 6.274294e-02  2.587949e-02 -8.674770e-04  6.398537e-03 
          261           262           263           264 
-2.207722e-02  6.961859e-03 -7.092074e-03  3.326304e-04 
          265           266           267           268 
-8.826976e-04  2.446652e-02  3.202071e-03 -4.300357e-03 
          269           270           271           272 
-8.697415e-03  1.632332e-02  1.139373e-02 -8.293938e-03 
          273           274           275           276 
 3.187131e-03 -2.838793e-03 -3.491220e-03  7.986199e-03 
          277           278           279           280 
-5.931380e-03  8.005507e-04 -1.515201e-03  6.203605e-03 
          281           282           283           284 
-1.763623e-03  2.263001e-02  2.058192e-03 -6.677623e-03 
          285           286           287           288 
-6.068511e-04  1.232161e-02  1.137790e-02  1.129776e-02 
          289           290           291           292 
 1.467367e-02 -1.221627e-02 -1.236961e-02  2.468580e-03 
          293           294           295           296 
-1.562174e-02  2.392474e-03 -2.466936e-04  9.032847e-03 
          297           298           299           300 
 7.028428e-03 -1.605058e-02  1.090764e-01  3.823460e-03 
          301           302           303           304 
-3.617284e-04 -3.620753e-03 -1.493839e-03  1.757362e-03 
          305           306           307           308 
 4.024892e-03  1.011166e-03  3.607874e-04  2.564815e-04 
          309           310           311           312 
 1.339123e-03  7.928470e-04 -1.579597e-03  5.422977e-03 
          313           314           315           316 
-2.079001e-03  9.967008e-03  9.050382e-03 -8.922487e-03 
          317           318           319           320 
-1.695307e-04  1.028737e-02  1.216367e-02  3.031379e-03 
          321           322           323           324 
-1.263116e-02 -1.537278e-02  2.242444e-04  2.426469e-03 
          325           326           327           328 
-2.664895e-03  3.884286e-03  6.880529e-03 -5.927206e-04 
          329           330           331           332 
 9.830635e-03  1.280008e-03  1.424032e-02 -7.288540e-04 
          333           334           335           336 
-9.240581e-04  3.195132e-04 -4.259236e-03 -2.214205e-03 
          337           338           339           340 
-6.881941e-03 -6.423759e-03 -2.609067e-03 -3.503663e-05 
          341           342           343           344 
 2.788641e-03  1.372338e-03  6.089936e-04  9.587636e-04 
          345           346           347           348 
 3.785345e-03 -2.026423e-03 -1.177728e-03  6.512821e-04 
          349           350           351           352 
-3.906498e-04 -8.785059e-03 -1.431750e-03 -2.324442e-04 
          353           354           355           356 
-1.076415e-03  1.441769e-03 -1.714267e-03 -1.674929e-03 
          357           358           359           360 
 8.652113e-04  1.238680e-03 -7.712385e-04  2.297910e-02 
          361           362           363           364 
 2.757363e-03 -1.088451e-05 -7.907335e-03 -4.752825e-03 
          365           366           367           368 
-1.202807e-03  5.597340e-03 -2.864217e-04  8.340569e-04 
          369           370           371           372 
-3.930913e-03 -5.725912e-03  4.980890e-04  3.697257e-03 
          373           374           375           376 
 5.995110e-03 -1.339679e-03 -9.186386e-03  8.241024e-03 
          377           378           379           380 
-6.799925e-03 -3.594279e-03  3.265258e-03  3.038261e-03 
          381           382           383           384 
-9.738195e-04  1.535296e-03 -8.603250e-04 -4.378884e-03 
          385           386           387           388 
-2.952824e-03  2.063849e-03 -4.624888e-03  3.525655e-03 
          389           390           391           392 
-5.207749e-03 -9.276466e-04  1.684872e-03  2.511384e-03 
          393           394           395           396 
-2.189145e-03 -1.098284e-02 -4.546533e-03 -1.349024e-03 
          397           398           399 
-5.619031e-04 -5.592868e-03  8.620104e-03 
#they’re not so go to add them
> names(csr)<-row.names(data)
Error in names(csr) <- row.names(data) : 
  'names' attribute [200] must be the same length as the vector [199]
```

Comment: Could you provide us with a sample of both files read by `read.csv` and `read.nexus`? This way we could reproduce and better analyze why you had a lost sample

Comment: @luizbarcelos thanks for the reply. What would be the best way to do this - from what I understand there is no option to share files on stack overflow.

Comment: No need to be the entire file, just an example with a few rows of each as part of the question so we can grasp the idea

Comment: @luizbarcelos sorry but I'm not sure how to do this with a nexus file. When I use `head(et)` the result is not an organized matrix that I could copy-paste. Here is the .csv file                                             
 `name SR
Gallus_gallus 0.321453901
Bucephala_albeola 0.409266409
Philomachus_pugnax 0.423076923
Sarkidiornis_melanotos 0.439914163
Geopelia_cuneata 0.441064639
Cereopsis_novaehollandiae 0.44200627
Platalea_minor 0.442982456
Anas_discors 0.443298969
Struthio_camelus 0.443375278`